# How to fix: Cannot convert value of type: GameData - Codeable, to expected argument Data

Tags: swift, function, data-conversion

I am attempting to decode my JSON response `data` from type: `AnyObject?` back into something that can be printed out in the console / interacted with.

reading back the data, before decoding prints `projectName.GameData`

Here is the breakdown, data comes back from the response as type: `Any?` Because it sent up as

```
class GameData : Codable {

    var isPlayerOneTurn: Bool!
    var wasCreated: Bool!
    var playerOne: String!
    var playerTwo: String!
    var board: [[Int]]!

   init() {

    }
}
```

The current error I am getting when attempting to decode is `Cannot convert value of type 'GameData' to expected argument type 'Data'`

code :

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dataTest = try? decoder.decode(GameData.self, from: data)
```

Am I missing a correct init() method  on the GameData class?

UPDATE:
data was changed to type `Data` here: thank you @rmaddy for the comment pointing this out.

```
 let data = data as? Data

 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 let dataTest = try? decoder.decode(GameData.self, from: data!)

 print("data: \(String(describing: dataTest))")
```

the print line still shows `data: Optional(projectName.GameData)`

What is wrong here still, not allowing me to view the values of the class GameData?

Comment: `data` needs to be of type `Data`.

Comment: Add a `description` method to your `GameData` class. BTW - `GameData` should probably be a struct, not a class.

Comment: tip: although you should NOT be doing either, you can do `data as! Data` so that you don't have to do `data!`. But I would put a `guard` with an assertion failure instead.

Comment: @Kubee thank you for the response! will take that advice.

Answer (score 0):

The print line mentioned in the question, was the value of the game object decode.. That was all XCode would print out - the name of the original object before decoding. Using `dataTest.myValue` worked when accessing data from the object.